# byte array of different length returned by BASE64Decoder class

Tags: java, security, base64, aes

I am trying to do a base64 decode of my string key, but every time it returns byte array of different length. Is it valid, or can I return fixed byte length of 32?

```
private byte[] base64DecodeOfKey(String keyval)
            throws JingEncryptionException {
    try {
        return new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(keyval);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JingEncryptionException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Test Case:

```
    byte[] decodeBufferrrrrrr;
    decodeBufferrrrrrr = new Base64().decode("=======================");
    System.out.println("decode:::::::"+decodeBufferrrrrrr);
    String encdata = new Base64().encodeAsString(decodeBufferrrrrrr);
    System.out.println("Encode:::"+encdata);
```

Output:

```
decode:::::::[B@535b58
Encode:::
```

Comment: You're probably forgetting to [pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: (`java.util.Base64` is the public API for encoding/decoding Base64. (Since 1.8.))

Comment: @Marcus I am applying padding problem is when these special characters comes, code is not decoding exact length byte array.

Comment: `=======================` doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

Base 64 decoding is deterministic: the same input should always result in the same output. So for base 64, the same base 64 string should always return the same byte array.

Probably the issue lies in the input, not in the function. Note that you should never use `sun` internal classes - the API and implementation may change at any time. Use either Guava, Apache Commons Codec or the internal Bouncy Castle codec instead.

Comment: do decoding of string of special character and than encoding it will return same string?

Comment: What special character? There are 64 characters possible for base 64 + carriage return/line feed and of course one or two `=` characters at the end.

Comment: NOTE: The pad character (=) does not have a binary representation in BASE64; it is inserted into the BASE64 text as a placeholder to maintain 24-bit alignment.  http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html

Comment: Got a solution to the problem, best way is to convert it UTF-8, the binary format.

Comment: If you've got a solution, then please post it as an answer. In this case it's very likely I will downvote though.

Answer (score -1):

Got a solution to the problem, best way is to convert it UTF-8, the binary format.As ASCII representation for "*","?" etc are unknown.

Comment: Keys are not text. Passwords may be text before they are converted to keys using a Key Derivation Function (KDF) like PBKDF2. Warned you :)